# Coordinates of a vector with respect to two bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering, given $[x]_B=[x]_C$ and both bases $B=\left\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n \right\}$ and $C=\left\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n \right\}$ are n-dimensional for vector space $V$, is it mandatory that both bases are equivalent, that is $B=C$?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  The easiest counterexample would be $x=0$.  Or for a non-trivial counterexample: consider $B = \{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ and $C=\{(1,0), (18,11)\}$.  Then $x=3b_1 = 3c_1$ has the same coordinates in both bases.